# Setting the duration of an image view

Tags: image, duration

Not lying when I say there is NO info out there on this topic. 
Maybe I'm not using the correct search terms but basically I want my image view to load for a set duration, say 5 seconds.

Alternatively, how does one pop back a view by tapping anywhere on the current screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And after the duration has elapsed, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Hi, building an iOS iPad app on Xcode. From a button, I want the image view to load for a given duration then close or hide itself and return to the previous view. The hidden image view must be enabled so user can view it again if they wish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question so I can post my code.

.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *lionCloseUp;


-(IBAction)lion;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)lion {
UIImage *lion = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lion-closeup.jpg"];
[lionCloseUp setImage:lion];
```

}

Comment: Note that you can edit your original question to add code -- that's the preferred way.  Normally you should only "answer" your question if you've worked out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down.  To have the image disappear you need to use a timer.  So research how to implement a timer in Objective-C.  (Note: There's plenty of info out there on timers, so *don't* just turn around and ask that as a question, at least not until you've tried something.)

(Next you'd need to define what you mean by "pop back a view".  If you literally mean that then you'd probably want to use a navigation controller.  Again, plenty of info out there if you look for it, but expect to spend several days experimenting.)

(On the other hand, if you just want the image to disappear, set it to "hidden".)

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. I had searched but setting an image duration etc. Implementing a timer has returned lots of very useful posts.